# How to detect if a cell is empty when reading Excel files using the xlrd library?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I handle Excel files using the functions **row_values** and **col_values**:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook( filename )
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
  sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name( sheet_name )    
  # ...
  row_values = sheet.row_values( rownum ) 
  # ...
  col_values = sheet.col_values( colnum )
```

For example, **I get col_values as list**. What if I meet an empty cell in some column? For example a cell (1,1) is not empty, a cell (1,2) is empty and a cell (1,3) is not empty? How can I detect that the cell (1,2) is empty?

Is this true that I get a list with an empty string as a value of an empty cell (for most well-known programs which generate Excel files)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could be explicit and check that `sheet.cell_type(rowno, colno) in (xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK)` but the docs state the value will be `u''` where those are the case anyway.

Instead of using `row_values`, you could also use `row(n)` which returns a list of `Cell` objects which have `.value` and `.cell_type` attributes.

Comment: This is almost 8 years later and I'm getting `'Cell' object has no attribute 'cell_type'`

Comment: @AliTou this may be a roundabout way, but I just convert the cell value to a string and compare it to an empty string (e.g `cell_value = str(cell.value); cell_empty = (cell_value == ""))`